# Powershell - Select File Name instead of full path and file name

Tags: powershell, search, full-text-search

I'm sure this is so simple you may roll your eyes at it.  I cannot figure out how to suppress the full path of the file when I get a match.

I only need the file name, Line number and matched word.
I have a text file of 15K copybooks.  I need to know what program references any of them.
The script takes forever to run but I know of only one way to search all files in a directory looking for ANY or ALL of the contents in my file.

Can someone point out the error?  The full path is not needed and adds a step or two to my process to clean things up.

Regards,
-Ron

```
$searchWords=Get-Content "C:\Workspace\Missing.txt"
    
Foreach ($sw in $searchWords)
{
    Get-Childitem -Path "C:\Workspace\src" -Recurse -include "*.cbl" | 
    Select-String -Pattern "$sw" | 
    Select Path,LineNumber,@{n='SearchWord';e={$sw}}
}
```

Comment: Remove `Path,` from the `Select Path,...` statement

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen
That did not work.  The results were just Line number and search word.  I need the file the search word was found in.

Comment: Ahh, so you want the filename _instead_ of the path, my bad. Replace `Path` with `Filename`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen
That worked!!  Thank you!